Automorphic elements

Given two elements $x,y$ in a group, how can you quickly check whether there exists an automorphism $\phi$ such that $\phi(x) = y$?

This seems well known but I can't find it online anywhere.
Obviously the order of $x$ and $y$ are equal, but this is not sufficient (consider the elements in $S_4 (12)34$ and $(12)(34)$ which both have order 2 but are not automorphic).
If it is not known for all groups, is it possible to solve this just for abelian groups? It might be helpful to use the Finitely Generated by Cyclic group representation.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I think for $G$ a finite abelian group, $x,y \in G$ are related by an automorphism if and only if they have the same order and the same index in a minimal cyclic factor containing them. This is just on vibes of the top of my head, so take with a grain of salt!

I suppose it depends on how you are given the two elements.

I strongly suspect that this is very difficult for finite groups in general, and probably of the same order of difficulty as computing the automorphism group of a group. The best known complexity estimate for that is $|G|^{O(\log |G|)}$, which is easy to prove. I don't know about abelian groups - that is almost certainly much easier and might reduce to Smith Normal Form calculations.

@diracdeltafunk In general, elements in a finite abelian groups are not necessarily contained in a cyclic direct factor.

The case of finite abelian groups reduces easily to the case of finite abelian $p$-groups. So let $G$ be a finite abelian $p$-group. The orbits of the automorphism group of $G$ should be the sets $(\Omega_{i}(G) \setminus \Omega_{i-1}(G)) \cap (\mho_{j}(G) \setminus \mho_{j+1}(G))$, where $\Omega_{i}(G) = { g \in G : g^{p^{i}} = 1 }$ and $\mho_{j}(G) = { g^{p^{j}} : g \in G }$. In other words, two element are in the same orbit if they have the same order and the same $p$-height. (A drawing in terms of "boxes" would help here.)

This is known to be decidable for free groups, via Whitehead's algorithm. This algorithm gives an exponential upper bound for the time complexity of this problem in free groups, but the complexity has been conjectured to be polynomial. So the word "quickly" is unknown in this case!

This is difficult in general since two elements that satisfy the same first order formulas may not be conneted by an automorphism.

For $G\cong C_p$, the check is immediate for every $x,y\in G$.

For abelian groups, this intersects with the discrete logarithm problem, which is computationally difficult (the intersection may be easy though): take the group of units of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q^$, which is cyclic, then the discrete logarithm problem takes two elements $a, b\in \mathbb{F}_q^$ and determines if there exists some exponent $m$ such that $b^m=a$. If we take $a$ to be a known generator for $\mathbb{F}_q^*$, then there exists some $m$ such that $b^m=a$ if and only if there exists an automorphism taking $a$ to $b$.
